# Chrome devtools hover window

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging in Chrome, you can hovering over an object/array and a window pops up that allows you to see the values of the properties within. Is there any way to resize that window, similar to how you can do that in Eclipse?

I know you can add the object/array to the watch list, but resizing the window would be on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Not aware that this can be done but a close alternative is to use the Scope panel on the right hand side, this can be resized and used to easily view objects at the scope of the current debug point.

Is great as you don't lose a deeply nested view by accidentally hovering off the window.